# If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges, $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$, does $\int_{0}^{\infty} f'(x)dx$ also converge?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges, and $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$, does $\int_{0}^{\infty} f'(x)dx$ also converge?

Comment: The derivative may not even exist.

Comment: Try $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}$.

Comment: @Gary One may object that $f$ is not continuous in $0$, but the "everywhere" in the wording needs to be precised whether continuity is on $[0,\infty)$ or $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @zwim Yes, you have a point.

Comment: Assuming $f'$ exists for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, so that the integral is defined, we have $$\int_0^\infty f'(x)\,dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}f(N)-\lim_{\epsilon\to0}f(\epsilon)$$ so the question is really whether those two limits exist.

Comment: Note, the edit by Adam Rubinson has rendered the comments here largely obsolete.

Comment: Following the comment from Barry Cipra, it is straightforward to construct a counterexample e.g. taking $f(x)=\sin x^2$.

Comment: A counterexample is in the answer by @JackD'Aurizio to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736587/improper-integrals-is-it-possible-to-have-a-non-bounded-function-such-that-its).

Comment: Sorry if my edit was not what OP intended. But it seems like the likely intended question of OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(e^x)\:dx < \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(e^x)\:dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But the integral of its derivative $e^x\cos(e^x)$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

The result is not true. Let $\varphi \in {\mathcal C}^1({\mathbb R})$ be such that

- $\varphi(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$
- $\varphi(x) = 0$ when $x\not\in [0, 1]$
- $\int_0^1\varphi(x) d x = 1$

Let $f: [0, \infty)\to {\mathbb R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \varphi(k^2(x-k))$ for $x\in [k, k+1)$.

Then $\int_0^\infty f(x) d x  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} <\infty$ but $\int_0^\infty f'(x) d x$ cannot converge because $f$ reaches the maximum and the minimum of $\varphi$ on every interval $[k, k+1)$ for $k\ge 1$.

Comment: You've given a really abstract example to an almost trivial problem.

Comment: @Martund "trivial" is completely subjective. I have given a valid example.

Comment: I've never said your example is invalid. But a child is asking whether $1$ is more or $2$, and you're answering that $k+1>k\forall k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @Martund Please post another example!

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{\infty} f'(x)dx = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(f(x)\right) - f(0).$

The answer to the question is no. Let's start with a "bar graph"- looking function:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}2^{n} & n \leq x < n+\frac{1}{4^n},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \\   0 & \text{otherwise}.  \end{cases}$$

The area under each "bar" is $\ 1,\ \frac{1}{2},\ \frac{1}{4},\ \frac{1}{8}, ...,\ \frac{}{} $ so the total area under the graph is just $2.$ More importantly, it converges as $n \to \infty.$

Now all we need to do is make each ends of the "bar" differentiable. One way to do this is to make each "bar" into a sine curve, for example:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}(\sin\left((2\pi x)4^n - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + 1)2^n & n \leq x < n+\frac{1}{4^n},\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} \\   0 & \text{otherwise}.  \end{cases}$$